# How to remove term from wp-json categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to get rid of certain terms in my `/wp-json/v2/categories` response, namely `uncategorized` but i have no clue, how properly to respond with **nothing**. because right now, i still get a response item (in this case `false`) or an empty value, but i`d rather remove the whole response

```
function so123_rest_prepare_category(WP_REST_Response $response, WP_Term $item, WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    if (in_array($item->term_id, [1, 62])) {
        $response = false;
    }

    return $response;
}

add_filter('rest_prepare_category', 'so123_rest_prepare_category', 10, 3);
```

i also tried `unset($response)` and `unset($response->data)`, but that leads to fatal error or `Undefined variable $response`

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you imagine "remove the whole response" would actually look like. If you are not responding with at least an empty string - then what _do_ you want to respond with? A different HTTP status code, like a 404? Or what _exactly_?

Comment: in the image i attached, you can see the entry 4. i want to remove that. maybe i`m looking in the wrong spot. not sure about that..

Comment: Ah, okay, that is different from how I understood your phrasing initially. But you're in the wrong spot for that, I think - this is the hook for modifying a _single_ term's data, and even if you return `false`, that won't make the entry in the array on the "upper level" of this disappear. You'll need to find a hook that allows you to modify that whole array that gets returned, and unset the 4th item in that.

Comment: `get_items` might be the more appropriate place to look, I think? https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php#L298 If you hook into `rest_category_query` there, and modify the arguments that will get passed to `get_terms`, I think that should do the trick.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/ - the `exclude` argument should allow you to just pass your array of term ids that you don't want in the result.

Comment: thanks @CBroe: `rest_category_query` was the proper filter for the task. it also has the option to pass an array with exclues. feel free to add your comment as an answer and gain some points ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rest_prepare_category`, you're in the wrong spot for this, I think - this is the hook for modifying a single term's data, and even if you return false, that won't make the entry in the array on the "upper level" of this disappear.

`rest_category_query` is the more appropriate place to get this done. using that you can manipulate the query parameters - and specify terms ids you explicitly want to `exclude` via the option of the same name.

```
function so75613342_rest_category_query(array $prepared_args, WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    if ($request['context'] === 'view') {
        $prepared_args['exclude'] = [1, 62];
    }

    return $prepared_args;
}

add_filter('rest_category_query', 'so75613342_rest_category_query', 10, 2);
```